# Module to display dropdown options from database table

Tags: component, development, module, database

I have a module which has dropdown select boxes. I have a table in the database, which is associated to a component, which the module is associated with.

If the component database table has data in it, how can I get the module to display the data in a dropdown and if selected it will show the results on a separate page?

For example, I have the following dropdowns in the module:

```
    <label for="airport">Airport:</label>
        <select id="airport" name="airport">
            <option selected="selected" value="A">Any Airport</option>
            <option value="LGW">Gatwick</option>
            <option value="MAN">Manchester</option>
        </select>
```

In the database, there is a table called "dep", it has either MAN or LGW in it. If the user selects LGW from the dropdown and then clicks search, I want the component to load all of the data from the database which has got LGW in the table.

I have set the following Database query in the module, but how can I use this to show the data in the dropdowns and then show the correct results?

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();

$query = $db->getQuery(true);

$query->select($db->quoteName(array('mykey', 'hotelName', 'resortName', 'dep',     'startDate', 'sellingPrice')));
$query->from($db->quoteName('#__availability'));
$query->order('ordering ASC');


$db->setQuery($query);

$results = $db->loadObjectList();
```

Comment: Currently what data the module's drop-down is showing? Meaning, you can definitely query the database from within the module. But what exactly you are after? Do you want to customize the module and change what it's doing, you want to create it from scratch, or you just need general info about the approach? Please clarify, otherwise the question is to broad and not clear. In case you are asking for code, you should also present some code here.

Comment: The update of your question gave a whole new dimension of what you are asking. So currently the module is already able to display data from your table. All you need is to make the component showing its content which its column has the chosen value from the dropdown?

Comment: The module isn't showing any data from the table, it's hardcoded that way, would be good to get the module to display the data (in the dropdowns) and then if chosen take the user to the results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can fill the from like below:

```
<label for="airport">Airport:</label>
<select id="airport" name="airport">
    <option selected="selected" value="A">Any Airport</option>
<?php
foreach ($results as $result)
{
    echo "<option value='{$result->dep}'>{$result->dep}</option>";
}
?>
</select>
```

Then process the form regularly or by an AJAX method.

Comment: Thanks very much, if I have lots of items in there set to the same Airport, it's bringing up multiple versions of the Airports, so rather than just having LGW and MAN, it's bringing up all of the records, so there are lots of LGW and lots of MAN, any ideas how I can only show one of each without the repeats?

Comment: Use `DISTINCT` keyword. For example: `$query = "SELECT DISTINCT dep FROM #__availability ORDER BY ordering ASC";`

Comment: Or use `group()` method. For example: `$query->group(dep);`.

Comment: Thanks, that works great. However, how can I use the $query->group on multiples? So if I want to group 'dep' and 'resortName' ?

Comment: Try this: `$query->group(array('dep', 'resortName'));`.

Comment: I've just tried that, but it's now showing one of each 'resortName' but then various 'dep' data

Comment: Check this answer: [stackoverflow.com/questions/2183373/mysql-group-by-two-columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2183373/mysql-group-by-two-columns)

Comment: If you only intend to make the first option the selected option, there is no need to declare `selected="selected"` ... it is the default behavior.  If the option `value` attribute holds the same string as the option text, then there is no need to declare the `value` attribute (`value='{$result->dep}'`). Form submissions and javascript action will all assume the text value if there is no `value` attribute.

Comment: @Rusty In the future, when you have mysql-related questions, please supply your db table details and your desired result set from your sample data so that we can confidently construct an appropriate query for you.